# Mass of moving body

Tags: special-relativity

If a body moving with a velocity (v) then  what would be the mass of body in the frame of body ? And if I am trying to move a body with speed relative to C then how much energy I have to give ?

Answer (score 0):

Using the energy-momentum equation:
$$E^2=p^2c^2+m^2c^4$$
We can see that the mass of the body in its own frame (where $p=0$) is its (rest) energy divided by $c^2$:
$$m=\frac{E}{c^2}$$
Kinetic energy is the difference between the total energy and the rest energy:
$$T=E-E_{0}=mc^2\left(\gamma-1\right)=mc^2\left({\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}}-1\right)$$
This is the amount of energy you have to transfer to the particle in order for it to reach the speed $v$.

Comment: Than what is the mass observed by body itself if it is moving ? Is it m' = m/(1- v^2/c^2)*(1/2) or simply m?

Comment: Well, even if you think in terms of rest mass and relativistic mass, which in my opinion it is not a really good idea, the mass of the body in its own frame will still be its rest mass.

Comment: Some people argue that the mass of the body increases with the speed, but that is not what happens. The mass of an object is not changing. Using the natural units ($c=1$), $m^2=E^2-p^2$.
When an object is moving relative to some reference frame, according to that frame, it will have different energy $(E')$ and, of course, a different momentum $(p')$, but its mass will be the same $E'^2-p'^2=m^2$.

Comment: Than what m' = m /(1- v^2/c^2)^(1/2) Tell's

Comment: However, if you still want to think about the relativistic mass (which I do not recommend), you can say that the mass of an object that is moving relative to some inertial frame of reference ($S'$) is (as seen from $S'$ frame) $m=m_{0}\gamma$, where $m_{0}$ is its rest mass. But that's really because it has different energy-momentum according to the S' reference frame.